# MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

When I use retrofit using https://api.github.com/users it works without problems but when I switch the information where it matches the values I have the following error appears, com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader. setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

MainActivity code :

```
package com.example.databasegames

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.databasegames.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import retrofit2.HttpException
import java.io.IOException


const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

       setupRecyclerview()

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {

            val response = try {
                RetrofitInstance.api.getData()
            }catch (e: IOException){
                Log.e(TAG , e.toString())
                return@launchWhenCreated
            }catch (e: HttpException){
                Log.e(TAG , "HttpException")
                return@launchWhenCreated
            }
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null){
                myAdapter.todos = response.body()!!
            }
            else{
                Log.e(TAG , "Response is not successfully")
            }
        }

    }

    private fun setupRecyclerview() = binding.recyclerView.apply {
         myAdapter = MyAdapter()
         adapter = myAdapter
         layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        
    }
}

RetrofitInstance.object :


package com.example.databasegames

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitInstance {

    val api: ApiService by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://overhand-seam.000webhostapp.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}


Data class (GamesItems) :


package com.example.databasegames

data class GamesItem(
    val id : Int,
    val name: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val emulator: String
)


Adapter :

package com.example.databasegames

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.databasegames.databinding.GamesBinding


class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(){

    inner class TodoViewHolder(val binding: GamesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val diffCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<GamesItem>(){

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: GamesItem, newItem: GamesItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: GamesItem, newItem: GamesItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }


    }

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this , diffCallback)
    var todos : List<GamesItem>
        get() = differ.currentList
        set(value){differ.submitList(value)}


    override fun getItemCount() = todos.size


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(GamesBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        ))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
      holder.binding.apply {
          val todo = todos[position]
          name.text = todo.name
          emulator.text = todo.emulator
          Glide.with(image.context).load(todo.imageUrl).into(image)
      }



    }




}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"


}
```